# Implement function template to fill multi-dimensional objects

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, c++14, template-meta-programming

Filling multi-dimensional objects (arrays, nested standard containers, etc) in C++ has always been annoying to me. Nested loops are usually used. For example, to fill a 3-dimensional object `obj` with value `v`, you may write something like

```
for (auto& x : obj) {
  for (auto& y : x) {
    for (auto& z : y) {
      z = v;
    }
  }
}
```

Such loops are code noise, being tedious to write and also hamper code reading. I'm thinking about writing a function template to perform the filling. Ideally, with such a function template, you should be able to write something like

```
fill(obj, v);
```

Any ideas?

Currently, I have a function template [`make_multi()`](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/CPP_Utility/blob/master/manual.md#make_multi) to make multi-dimensional objects. So you can do

```
// assuming `obj` is a 3x3x3 nested `std::vector`
obj = make_multi<std::vector>(v, 3, 3, 3);
```

Besides being more code than the ideal case, this solution is a performance nightmare. Ultimately, I have to look for better ways.

Comment: If the value you initialize with never changes why not just use the constructor?

Comment: @NathanOliver The value to use may not be known at construction time of the multi-dimensional object.

Comment: Then delay the construction until you know the value?  I don't think you would use it until you knew what to fill it with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a flattened foreach:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename Range, typename Func>
    constexpr auto flat_foreach(Range&& r, Func& f, int)
        -> decltype(void(f(std::forward<Range>(r)))) {f(std::forward<Range>(r));}

    template <typename Range, typename Func>
    constexpr void flat_foreach(Range&& r, Func& f...) {
        for (auto&& i : r)
            flat_foreach(std::forward<decltype(i)>(i), f, 0);
    }
}

template <typename Range, typename Func>
constexpr void flat_foreach(Range&& r, Func f) 
{detail::flat_foreach(std::forward<Range>(r), f, 0);}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f3fbb8e0058be00). This is the non-greedy approach, passing the range off to the given function as shallow as possible.

Comment: Oh my... Such a difficult (at least in my eyes) task could come out with such an elegant solution! You definitely rock!

Comment: This thing definitely should be added to the standard library!

Comment: @Columbo I would love to see an explanation to this because I am impressed by your solution but honestly do not understand how it works.

Comment: @RamboRamon The second overload is selected if the first doesn't match. The first overload matches whenever the expression `f(std::forward<Range>(r))` is valid, i.e. when the given functor is applicable to the subrange given by `r`.

Comment: @Columbo Thanks for the comment, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the greedy counterpart to [@Columbo's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35015478/636019):

```
namespace detail {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    template<typename Elem, typename Func>
    constexpr void flat_foreach(Elem&& e, Func& f, long) {
        f(std::forward<Elem>(e));
    }

    template<typename Range, typename Func>
    constexpr auto flat_foreach(Range&& r, Func& f, int)
      -> decltype(begin(r), void(end(r))) {
        for (auto&& i : r) {
            flat_foreach(std::forward<decltype(i)>(i), f, 0);
        }
    }
}

template<typename Range, typename Func>
constexpr void flat_foreach(Range&& r, Func f) {
    detail::flat_foreach(std::forward<Range>(r), f, 0);
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ded5123e1b6b4424)</kbd>

The general advantage to this approach is that one can pass in a *generic* lambda/functor for `f`.

Comment: Really like this thing `-> decltype(void(begin(r)), void(end(r)))` :P  I think `Range&&` could simply be `Range&`.

Comment: @Lingxi : Agreed, I just wanted to maintain as much parity with Columbo's code as possible so that the _important_ differences between the two approaches were obvious. I only switched the varargs out for `long` due to strong personal bias. :-P

Comment: Due to strong personal bias, I used `char`, `int`, and `' '` (space character) throughout my library :-P Cheers!

Comment: `void(begin(r)), void(end(r))` could be `begin(r), void(end(r))`. Comma operator doesn't require the sub-expressions to be of the same type.

Comment: @Lingxi : If the type returned by `begin(r)` overloads `operator,` then bad things will happen without the cast.

Comment: @ildjarn And what bad things would that be?

Comment: @Columbo : A bit of testing proves your implication correct (as usual). I suppose that this is a non-issue because `operator,` is a binary operator and a void expression will not activate it.